# How to add frames to images (in shotwell)?

Tags: software-recommendation, printing, plugins, shotwell

I will be a photographer at an event and part of the deal is we offer on the spot editing, which includes cropping and photo adjustments. The organizer insists we offer adding frames to the pictures.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and most of the editing will be done in Shotwell. Is there a plugin to add frames to images? As in "click plugin icon", "click select frame", "choose frame", and voila, the picture is framed? If not, can some other application do this?

Answer (score 3):

I am a keen photographer and can confirm that. Shotwell doesn't currently have this capability.

There is an application available in the Ubuntu Software Centre that does with the simplicity you require. It's called Showfoto with Kipi plug ins. It also has cropping and spot editing capability.

When installed simply go to Decorate on the main menu bar to add frames.

All you need to do is to setup up the size of your outer and inner border and that will be your default for all your images until you decide to change it.  Very intuitive

Comment: Is there also a program that can do this for the Gnome desktop (apart from Gimp)? I wish Pinta had a frames feature.

Comment: Showfoto is part of the DigiKam suite designed for KDE. Works well in Gnome, unity and Ms Windows

Comment: Yes I know I can run KDE programs just as well as Gnome ones, I was just wondering as I like Pinta - thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to use cups with digiKam? Also are there any alternatives? I would like to know all my options.

Comment: This link may answer that your question about CUPS  http://www.tuxify.de/?p=635